# How to extend a template attribute using t-jquery and t-operation (Odoo 14)

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I want to change the name of button "Discount" in POS module. So I extend the template with this code , but doesn't works.

```
<t t-extend="DiscountButton">
         <t t-jquery="span[class='control-button js_discount']" t-operation="replace">
              <span class="control-button js_discount">
            <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
                <span> </span>
                <span>Discount(%)</span>
            </span>
         </t>
    </t>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Extension inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/qweb.html#template-inheritance) (in-place transformation):

```
<t t-inherit="pos_discount.DiscountButton" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <xpath expr="//span[hasclass('js_discount')]/span[2]" position="replace">
        <span>Discount(%)</span>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

The `extension` directive is used to alter the parent template in place.

***Edit:***

You can alter the template of the `DiscountButton`

```js
odoo.define('my_module_name.NewDiscount', function(require) {
    'use strict';

    var DiscountButton = require('pos_discount.DiscountButton');
    DiscountButton.template = "NewDiscount"
});
```

And add the js file to the point of sale assets:

```
<template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module_name/static/js/new_discount.js"></script>
      </xpath>
</template>
```

*I suppose you already defined the `NewDiscount` template and add it under the `qweb` entry of the manifest file.*

Comment: Thanks @Kenly , this works , what about adding new span and new template with js code ?   I tried this code (t-name) for adding new span , but still having problem                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               <t t-name="my_module_name.NewDiscount" owl="1">
        <span class='control-button js_new_discount'>
            <i class='fa fa-tag' /> New Discount
        </span>
</t>

Comment: You can alter the button template. Check my edit.